# How can I query an object and its related object in one time in Django

Tags: django

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    ..
    status = models.CharField(max_length=16, default="pending")

class Food(models.Model):
    ..
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)


{% for i in food %}
    {% for j in food.ingredients.all %}
```

In the for loop tag, I would like to list each food with its ingredients which the status is not "pending".

I don't want to use IF tag to check at client side because if food contains a lot of pending ingredients, it means that the server has to sent a lot of data that will never be used. The server supposes to sent only needed data.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: the template parsing doesn't happens at the client side! your template tags will be parsed at server side and only the generated html will be sent to the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all and from db design point of view, it is better if your status field is a list of choices. It would be something like this:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    NEW = 1
    PENDING = 2
    APPROVED = 3
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (NEW, 'New'),
        (PENDING, 'Pending'),
        (APPROVED , 'Approved'),
    )
    status = models.IntegerField(default=PENDING, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
```

Now since the relation is many to many and to get list of related ingredients, get a list of food items and then apply filter(in view using orm filter on each food item, or in template using !=)

```
food = Food.objects.all()
```

and in template(notice the difference in second line from your loop):

```
{% for i in food %}
    {% for j in i.ingredients.all %}
        {% if j.status != 2 %}
```

The problem with this approach is that for every food item  it will send db query which might not be efficient.
Instead you can do this in your view:

```
food = Food.objects.prefetch_related('ingredients')
```

which will bring all related ingredients in one query for all food items. The problem with prefetch_related is that you have to do any filtering also yourself.

Comment: Ah, I saw the mistake I made in the second line. prefetch_related() is very useful.